# Creating an array of cubes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, physics

The following program will be used for college physics research. So I'm working on a research project that involves creating unitcells in rectangular form. For now I'm working with a 3d cubic grid. My goal is to make more of these adjacent with each other.

Here is my current code (which you guys helped with): 
Right now it only makes one cube, can place random points on the cubic grid's vertices, and it can calculate the distance between points. How would I get matplotlib to produce more of these? Also, I need to be able to put points on the multiple cubes and I should be able to calculate the distance from a point in Cube A to a point in Cube B. Would I be able to produce multiple cubes in the same matplotlib by just doing a while loop? Also, what would it look like using numpy arrays? 
I feel as though the numpy arrays would be easy to create but I can't quite wrap my head around it.
Code I have so far:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, combinations
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d

parameter = np.arange(0,11,1)
xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(parameter, parameter, parameter)
valuesrange = np.zeros((11, 11, 11))
valuesrange2 = np.zeros((11, 11, 11))

count = 0

while (count < 2):
xint = np.random.randint(0,2)
yint = np.random.randint(0,2)
zint = np.random.randint(0,2)

if xint > 0:
    xint = np.random.randint(10,11, 22)  
else:
    xint = np.random.randint(0,1, 22)

if yint >0:
    yint = np.random.randint(10,11, 22)  
else: 
    yint = np.random.randint(0,1, 22)

if zint > 0:
    zint = np.random.randint(10,11, 22)  
else:
    zint = np.random.randint(0,1, 22)
count = count + 1
print(xint, yint, zint)
xint2 = np.random.randint(0,2)
yint2 = np.random.randint(0,2)
zint2 = np.random.randint(0,2)

if xint2 > 0:
    xint2 = np.random.randint(10,11, 22)  
else:
    xint2 = np.random.randint(0,1, 22)

if yint2 >0:
    yint2 = np.random.randint(10,11, 22)  
else: 
    yint2 = np.random.randint(0,1, 22)

if zint2 > 0:
    zint2 = np.random.randint(10,11, 22)  
else:
    zint2 = np.random.randint(0,1, 22)
print (count)
print(xint2, yint2, zint2)
distance = ((xint2-xint)**2 + (yint2 - yint)**2 + (zint2 - zint)**2)**.5
print ('distance:')
print (distance)

#xint = np.random.randint(0, 11, 22)
#yint = np.random.randint(0, 11, 22)
#zint = np.random.randint(0, 11, 22)
#distance formula = ((x2-x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 + (z2 - z1)**2)**.5 
valuesrange[[xint, yint, zint]]= np.random.random(22)
valuesrange[[xint, yint, zint]]= np.random.random(22)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
im = ax.scatter(xx, yy, zz, c = valuesrange, cmap=plt.cm.spectral_r, 
edgecolor = 'none', alpha = .7)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.colorbar(im)
fig.show()

#plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do have severe problems understanding the purpose of most of the code. What I can tell you is that you may of course put the cube creation in a function and call that function several times, possibly with different parameters, to obtain several scatter plots.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def make_cube(ax, n=10, offset=[0,0,0]):
    parameter = np.arange(0,n,1)
    xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(parameter, parameter, parameter)
    valuesrange = np.zeros((n,n,n))
    valuesrange = np.random.rand(n,n,n)
    x = xx+offset[0]; y=yy+offset[1];  z=zz+offset[2]
    sc = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c = valuesrange, cmap=plt.cm.spectral_r, vmin=0, vmax=1,
                    edgecolor = 'none', alpha = .7)
    return sc

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

sc1 = make_cube(ax,n=6)
sc2 = make_cube(ax,n=4, offset=[8,7,4])
# or use a loop:
#for i in range(4):
#    sc1 = make_cube(ax,n=i)

plt.colorbar(sc1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I think the part you may not be getting is the if/else statements. Those statements produce random points on vertices of the cube. Also, what is the use of the two different distributions of points in your cubic grid? Are those supposed to represent Unitcells? Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what they represent. You asked for a method to make more than one cube and this answer provides such a method. I made those two cubes different, but that is just to show how to use parameters, because I don't know (and I don't need to know) the purpose of all of this.

Comment: Okay. I think I understand this now (especially the parameters). Thanks for the help.